# New Instance of the page on Navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, navigation, instance, back-button

I have a few pages in an Application that require A-Synchronous calls to be made for about 2-3 minutes to get Synchronized, the user may navigate away from that page during Synchronization and can come back again after visiting multiple pages and the sync continues all the time he is on other pages as well, when I go to a page from sync-page  and press the Back button everything works fine.. but when i go to a page and navigate back to sync-page from Application Bar a new Instance of the Page is created and the Sync is just like Re-started.

Now i know every thing is working fine since new instance of a page is created when i call NavigationService.Navigate() , but what should i do in this scenario ? How to get the old instance of a page if it is there ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an "old" instance of a page and it's not guaranteed that a backwards navigation will reload the previous instance of the page, it may be a new instance of the same page, but restored to the same state (assuming you saved any).

If you are trying to provide backwards navigation from the application bar then a) you probably shouldn't because that's what the back button is for, and b) you should make sure you use `NavigationService.GoBack()` instead of `NavigationService.Navigate()` because **Navigate** will always launch a new instance of your page.

If the page you want to get to is not the previous page, then it sounds like you are trying to implement non-linear navigation for which there is a recipe on the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7).

By the sounds of your scenario, you should handle this long running process separately (away from the view) and then display it's progress or results in a view when the user navigates to the relevant page.